# How to solve ajax taking only the first row data when fetching data from php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having problem with my ajax code when I am trying to click update data into my database using ajax not to refresh the page. I am trying to have the user click on the button in each data that is taken from database. But the problem is that every time I click on each data it took only the first row of data. Can you help me to see what is wrong in my code?
**Ajax here**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>        
  $(function () {

    $('.vote').on('submit', function (e) {
    var vote =  $(this).attr("data-id");
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'file-includes/social-interaction/vote_action.php',
        data: {vote : vote},
        success: function (data) {
            alertify.log(data, "", 0);
            return false;
        }
      });

    });

  });

</script>
```

**Php Here**

```
    <?php   
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);
    require '../../core/database/connect.php';
    require '../../core/functions/general.php';
    require '../../core/functions/users.php';
    //mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    $current_file = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $current_file = end($current_file);
    if (logged_in() == true) {
        $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password_recover','type','allow_email', 'profile', 'quote','dob','status','current_occupation','location','skill','about_user','joined_date','phone','ban','fbpname','fbpurl','fb','fbn','website','whatsapp','profile_view');
        $user_id = $user_data['user_id'];
        if (user_active($user_data['username']) == false) {
            session_destroy();
            header('Location: index');
            exit();
        }
        if ($current_file !== 'change_password.php' && $current_file !=='logout.php' && $user_data['password_recover'] == 1) {
            header('Location: change_password?force');
            exit();
        }
    }
    $errors = array();
?>
<?php
protect_page();
if($_POST){
    $question_id = $_POST['question_id'];
    $answer_id = $_POST['answer_id']; 
    $rate = $_POST['score_input'];
    $user_id = $user_data['user_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vote_action WHERE answer_id = ".$answer_id." AND user_id=".$user_id."";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0)
       {
           echo 'You\'ve already voted for this answer';
        //mysql_query("DELETE FROM `vote_action` WHERE `answer_id` = '$answer_id' AND `user_id` = '$user_id'");
       }else{
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `vote_action` (`vote_id`, `question_id`, `user_id`, `rate_score`, `answer_id`) VALUES (NULL, '$question_id', '$user_id', '$rate', '$answer_id');");
         echo 'You\'ve voted for this answer the answer and give the user '.$rate.' Score(s)';
        }
}
?>
```

**And html file is here**

```
<form class="vote" data-id="<?php echo 'vote-'.$answer_id?>">
            <input type="hidden" data-id="<?php echo 'vote-'.$answer_id?>" value="<?php echo $question_id_get;?>" name="question_id_asnwer" class="vote">
            <input type="hidden" data-id="<?php echo 'vote-'.$answer_id?>" value="<?php echo $answer_id;?>" name="answer_id" class="vote">
            <!-- Small button group -->
<select id="first-disabled" name="score_input" data-id="<?php echo 'vote-'.$answer_id?>" class="selectpicker vote" data-hide-disabled="true" data-live-search="true" data-width="55%">
    <optgroup disabled="disabled" label="disabled">
      <option>Hidden</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="SCORE">
      <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">1</option>
      <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">2</option>
      <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">3</option>
      <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">4</option>
      <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">5</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
            <button type="submit" name="vote" class="btn-text" data-vote="<?php echo $answer_id; ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></i></button> <span>25 </span>
            </form>
```

Comment: Your example code seems to do much more than what you are having a problem with. You should try to minimize your example to just the code that relates to the question. Also, try to state what your code should do and how it fails more clearly. Currently, it's hard to know what *" every time I click on each data it took only the first row of data"* means

Comment: every time I click on the button that contain class="btn-text" in the form that has the class="vote"... Please help me with this. Help to adjust the ajax and html code... PHP code I just posted it whether you need to see it. Sorry for that I am trying to learn more about it too.

Comment: What **should happen**  *every time you click on the button that contain class="btn-text" in the form that has the class="vote"*? What **currently happens**?

Comment: When I clicked on the submit button, it insert into my database the first value, and I can't insert the other data below the first row... I think the problem is it takes only the first row value. Can you check my ajax and my form in html code? Thanks for replying sir.

Comment: When you say "row", do you mean "option", like these `<option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">1</option>`?

Comment: No sir, I mean the row in database

Comment: are you displaying some kind of listing in which each row has a separate form  with the button having `class="btn-text"` and you want to update every row accordingly in the database when you hit the button for that row ?

Comment: Sorry for late to reply, Yes sir. Can I do that... I want to update a listing record but it take only the first row always. How to solve that please?

Comment: Im sorry, "it take only the first row always" just doesnt explain what is happening in a way I can understand.

Comment: @DelightedD0D: Sorry for my English

Comment: No worries, I'd like to help, I just dont understand the problem :(

Comment: @DelightedD0D: Thanks very much now I solve it myself. I do it again and again to see how it goes wrong. Thanks for everyone here. Thanks very much for your replying.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it goes wrong. I have just found it. If someone meet the same problem you can see this. Thanks...
**This is my new ajax code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('.form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();
          var form_data = $(this).closest(".form").serialize();
          //alert(form_data); //I used this to see how my ajax get data from form but I don't want it to be show to user so I commented it out
          $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: 'file-includes/social-interaction/vote_action.php',
           data: form_data,
           success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
                alertify.log(data, "", 0);
            }
         });

        });
//event.preventDefault();
     });
</script>
```

**This is my new working php to post data**

```
<?php
protect_page();
if($_GET){
    $question_id = $_GET['question_id'];
    $answer_id = $_GET['answer_id']; 
    $rate = $_GET['score_input'];
    $user_id = $user_data['user_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vote_action WHERE answer_id = '".$answer_id."' AND user_id='".$user_id."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0)
       {
           echo 'You\'ve already voted for this answer';
        //mysql_query("DELETE FROM `vote_action` WHERE `answer_id` = '$answer_id' AND `user_id` = '$user_id'");
       }else{
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `vote_action` (`vote_id`, `question_id`, `answer_id`, `user_id`, `rate_score`) VALUES (NULL, '$question_id', '$answer_id', '$user_id', '$rate')");
         echo 'You\'ve voted for this answer the answer and give the user '.$rate.' Score(s)';
        }
}
?>
```

**And the last this is my working form:**

```
<form action="" class="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="<?php echo $question_id;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="answer_id" value="<?php echo $answer_id;?>" />
    <select id="first-disabled" name="score_input" class="selectpicker" data-hide-disabled="true" data-live-search="true" data-width="width:10%;">
    <optgroup disabled="disabled" label="disabled">
      <option>Give Score</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Useless Answer">
      <option>0</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Good Answer">
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Helpful Answer">
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-color-blue">
</form>
```